# Wildfly DB connection pool fails after database server restart

Tags: mysql, jboss, mariadb, wildfly, connection-pooling

Our wildfly (22) connection pool does not reconnect after a DB server restart / or a network outage.
In such a situation all the DB connections result in a

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=96578) Connection is closed
```

We have set the following `validation settings`:

```
<validation>
   <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
   <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
   <background-validation>true</background-validation>
   <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
</validation>
```

So as I understood the [documentation](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-datasource/how-to-automatically-reconnect-to-the-database-in-wildfly/) after max. 10s all DB connections should have been renewed. However that is not the case and the DB connection pool always returns 'closed connections'. Only a wildfly server restart helps in this case.
Any idea how to fix this?

[Somebody](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/230932) had the same problem, but no solution

Comment: Interesting article here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-datasource/how-to-automatically-reconnect-to-the-database-in-wildfly/. Try to set a `valid-connection-checker`. The list of available classes/extensions is available at:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/datasource_extensions1#doc-wrapper

Comment: @TacheDeChoco Interesting hint - I'll try that out and report back here! Thanks